# Class inheritance and the print/_str_() methods

Tags: python, string, printing

My apologies once again for asking another very junior question. For one reason or another, I can't yet seem to make the transition from Java to Python. I realize that Python has these built in methods that help the user do things. But I was wondering if the two following pieces of code are the same or if one is "more formal" in the sense that it is more commonly used in Java than the other.

```
def print()
    print "My name is___"
```

and

```
def _str_()
   print "My name is___"
```

Once again, either one of my methods might be completely wrong (my guess would be the "*str*" methods. In the interest of time, I have not written out the class name and other methods/attributes. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: if you still have your head in Java, think of `__str__` as the Python version of `toString`

Comment: I  would recommend you to read a little bit more about _Object Oriented Programming in Python_ before starting coding, your code has several OOP problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't define `print` because it's a keyword/built-in function.

The `__str__` function is used in classes.  When an instance of an object is converted to a string, this function is called.  Functions such as `print` do this internally.  You can also call `str(my_object_instance)`.

*Note the double underscores.*  A single one, like in the OP, isn't anything special.

---

Example (Python interactive):

```
>>> class A:                                                                                        
...   def __str__(self):                                                                            
...     return "I am an instance of A"                                                              
...                                                                                                 
>>> a_inst = A()                                                                                    
>>> print a_inst                                                                                    
I am an instance of A                                                                               
>>>
```

If you have any questions, leave a comment.

Comment: also note that `__str__(self)`, just like any other instance method takes one parameter - the object on which it is called

Answer (score 2):

`__str__`, `__len__`, `__contains__`, etc are **protocols** .

Any `__xxx___` has a special meaning, one seasoned pythonneer expect `xxx(obj1)` to calls `obj1.__xxx__()`.

But sometimes, the protocol is used with a keyword :

- `'a' in 'aaaaa'` is translated as `'aaaa'.__contains__('a')`.
- `print obj1` is translated as `print obj1.__str__()`.

Even if it has a special (transverse) meaning the implementation is like any other method, so it can be overriden by a descendant class.

Comment: You are oversimplifying things: often the `__xxx___` method only implements part of the protocol. For example `print obj1` is roughly  `print str(obj1)`, and `str(obj1)` *usually* calls `obj1.__str__()` but if you have an object with no `__str__` method it calls `__repr__` instead. Also `a + b` is usually `a.__add__(b)` but if that doesn't work will try `b.__radd__(a)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**The goals behind that methods are both legit (the sintax not too much)**, but which one to choose depends on what you're trying to do.

Maybe a simple example will help clear some things.

Let's define a `User` class:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is %s" % self.name

    def show(self):
        print "My name is %s" % self.name
```

**Note:** I changed the method name from `print` to `show` because in python 2.x `print` is a keyword so you can't use it.

Now let's try the `User` class to see the difference between `__str__` and `show`?:

```
>>> rik = User('Ricky')
>>> rik.show()
My name is Ricky
>>> rik.__str__()
'My name is Ricky'
>>> print rik
My name is Ricky
```

The code should explain itself.

#### `__str__` ([here the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__))

`__str__`  is a *Special Method Name* which means that when you call `print rik` python goes looking for `rik.__str__` if such method is defined then its called `rik.__str__()` and the string that returns will be printed.

Main point `__str__`:

- **should not** call `print`
- and **must** return a `string`.

#### `show`

On the other hand calling `show()` directly print the string (and return `None`). That's it.